# Why sources codes c++ in linux compile and does not start?

Tags: c++, xfce, gtkmm3, gtk4

Source codes c++ gtkmm3 gtk4 linux:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto app =
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
      "org.gtkmm.examples.base");
 
  Gtk::Window window;
  window.set_default_size(200, 200);
 
  return app->run(window);
}
```

I compiled them with next command in terminal:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags gtkmm-3.0 --libs gtk3)
```

and they does not start and I see next errors in console (terminal) on xubuntu 21.10 xfce (xfce4-panel 4.16.3 (Xfce 4.16))

```
user@myPC:~$ ./main

(process:39732): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 18:55:52.593: cannot register existing type 'GtkWidget'

(process:39732): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 18:55:52.593: cannot add class private field to invalid type '<invalid>'

(process:39732): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 18:55:52.593: cannot add private field to invalid (non-instantiatable) type '<invalid>'

(process:39732): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 18:55:52.593: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(process:39732): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 18:55:52.593: cannot register existing type 'GtkBuildable'

(process:39732): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 18:55:52.593: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed

(process:39732): GLib-CRITICAL **: 18:55:52.593: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(process:39732): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 18:55:52.593: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(process:39732): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 18:55:52.593: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

(process:39732): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 18:55:52.593: cannot add private field to invalid (non-instantiatable) type '<invalid>'

(process:39732): GLib-CRITICAL **: 18:55:52.593: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(process:39732): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 18:55:52.593: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

(process:39732): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 18:55:52.593: cannot add private field to invalid (non-instantiatable) type '<invalid>'
```

Why?

Comment: do you have the non-dev version of `libgtkmm` installed and all its dependencies?

Comment: Are those `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` and `#include <glib.h>` really necessary? It might be those headers do more than just declaring some functions and actually do register `GtkWidget` a second time and thus those warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may  need the package `gtk3-engines-xfce` or later to be installed.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gtk3-engines-xfce
```

Comment: No.  Package "gtk3-engines-xfce" is only for ubuntu 18.04.
I have Xubuntu 21.10 .I need solve my problem.

Comment: try this one : gtk3-engines-unico

Comment: I've installed "gtk3-engines-unico" to xubuntu 21.10 and I've errors, too.

Comment: Have you got in your environment some QT_ variables ? If yes can you paste here the name and values ?

Comment: I've installed "qt 5 dev package" ```apt install qtbase5-dev``` I've see next errors, too.

Comment: I was suspecting Qt to cause some problem using an other version of gtk. This is why I asked you your environment variables. Can you please paste the result of the command `env` in https://pastebin.com/ and then share the link in the next comment?

Answer (score 0):

I don't known the reason of it. I use gtkmm on mac os and I noticed I must use "g++ -std=c++11 to compile the source, or it will failed.
for your code, I think you just include <gtkmm.h> to get the program work. gtk.h and glib.h shoule be included by gtkmm.h already.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).